# DryIoc: Enabling 'throwIfUnresolved' always throw an exception

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, dryioc

I want to know name of dependencies that are missed (not injected)!

I Use this extensions:

- DryIoc.dll v4.0.7
- DryIoc.WebApi.dll v4.0.0
- DryIoc.Web.dll v4.0.0

and I tried to use throwIfUnresolved parameter to solve the problem

Like this:

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var container = new Container().WithWebApi(config, throwIfUnresolved: type => true);

        //...
    }
```

but after that I always get this exception even if there is no dependency!

> DryIoc.ContainerException: 'Unable to resolve ModelMetadataProvider IsResolutionCall
>     from Container with ambient ScopeContext DryIoc.AsyncExecutionFlowScopeContext without Scope
>    Where no service registrations found
>     and no dynamic registrations found in 0 of Rules.DynamicServiceProviders
>     and nothing found in 0 of Rules.UnknownServiceResolvers'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var container = new Container()
            .WithWebApi(
                config,
                throwIfUnresolved: type => type.IsController());

        //...
    }
```